# Axis2 generates wrong WSDL, where is the error?

Tags: wsdl, apache-axis

I've used NetBeans plugin "Axis2 Support" to create webservice from my pojo class.

When I go to create the client from wsdl file I get some errors.

Here is the message:

```
[ERROR] missing required property "style" of element "operation"
```

This is an example of element operation that generates the error:

```xml
<wsdl:operation name="addObjectPropertyAssertion">
  <wsdl:input message="ns:addObjectPropertyAssertionRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:addObjectPropertyAssertion"/>
  <wsdl:fault message="ns:EcourbStorageServiceInvalidURIException" name="EcourbStorageServiceInvalidURIException" wsaw:Action="urn:addObjectPropertyAssertionEcourbStorageServiceInvalidURIException"/>
  <wsdl:fault message="ns:EcourbStorageServiceInvalidURIReferenceException" name="EcourbStorageServiceInvalidURIReferenceException" wsaw:Action="urn:addObjectPropertyAssertionEcourbStorageServiceInvalidURIReferenceException"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Deploying web service I've just some errors like this (I will correct it after, I don't think is the cause)

```
[WARN] We don't support method overloading. Ignoring [addRDFTriple]
```

Using some simple service operation in browser it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: the problem was methods with void return. Set a return value of any type solves the problem.